# Watin's LogonDialogHandler not working for Firefox 3.6

Tags: watin

I'm writing automation scripts for a website using WatiN. when I browse to a particular url, a authentication dialog pops up. I have following code to handle the dialog. This code basically enters the specified

```
// Create a logon dialog handler
LogonDialogHandler ldh = new LogonDialogHandler(user, password);
browser.DialogWatcher.Add(ldh); 
browser.GoTo("URL that pops up the authentication dialog");
```

Now this works just fine in IE. But in Firefox, the dialog appears and nothing happens after that. (No username or password entered in their text boxes)

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: r u using the latest watin version?

Comment: @alonp: I'm using latest version of WatiN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but the automation of firefox popups/dialogs is not supported by WatiN at this moment (WatiN 2.1 and lower). It probably can be done but this is not high on my priority list.

Comment: Any chances to push it up the priority list? This is very critical to automating sharepoint websites