# Log in pop up in Firefox

Tags: c#, watin

I am using c# WaTin tool for automation testing. Now during one of the scenario, I get a pop up that asks for log in credentials even after I am already logged in. The pop up does not appear in Internet Explorer. What should I use to handle this type of pop up ?

Comment: how are you so sure this isn't an actual bug in the site?

Comment: @Koen, as he has said in the title, it is happening in Firefox.

Comment: Are you able to given some information on the type of authentication used? E.g. is it basic authentication, or Windows Authentication.

Comment: @Adrian - it is basic authentication. It does not concern windows authentication. The one we need while we log in to any website

Comment: Ok, so have you checked/monitored the requests sent to see if the server is sending back a 401 challenge HTTP status code? Have you also checked to see if the authorization header disappears from your request which triggers the popup?

Comment: Does this happen when using firefox manually? If so, the application code is behaving that way in firefox and you need to figure out why.

Comment: @mot - Yes, the pop up appears manually also.

Comment: So this is a general bug in your website, it's not an automation issue. You don't want the automation to work around this, you want it to fail so developers will fix it.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, the WatiN project has been dormant for more than 2 years. Last checkin was 2012/04/23 in Sourceforge. The main developer has also stated that [dialog automation in Firefox is  not supported in WatiN 2.1 and lower](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8502007/2641278). So you're likely to run into more issues issue after the website is fixed by the developers.

Comment: @adrian - thank you. I will look into it and update if I find anything